# How 2 paragraphs in one line html

Tags: javascript, html, css, paragraph

i'm making an test html webpage and i need to put 2 paragraphs in one line because i have an script for the two paragraphs, but i cant put it into only one line (sorry for my bad english)
the full html code is here: https://pastebin.com/gZmLXxPR , the script:https://pastebin.com/wc01gjUy ,
and the css style: https://pastebin.com/d7d3AJFN

```js
var counter = 1;

function upvote() {
  counter = counter + 1;

  document.getElementById("Likes")
    .innerHTML = counter + " Likes";
}
```

```html
<h1>PANDA</h1>
<img id="imagen1" src="img/panda.jpg">
<p color="blue" id="texto"><em>LIKE SI ES MONO</em></p>
<div id="section">
  <td>
    <p id="Likes">1 Likes</p>
    <p id="DisLikes">1 DisLikes</p>
  </td>
</div>
<img id="upvote" src="img/like.png" hspace="20" vspace="10" onclick="upvote()">
<img id="downvote" src="img/dislike.png" hspace="20" vspace="10" onclick="downvote()">
```

Ok, the paragraphs code is that:

```
<div id="section">
<td>
   <p id="Likes">1 Likes</p>
   <p id="DisLikes">1 DisLikes</p>
</td>
</div>
```

so i need to put that in only one line

Comment: You could set their display to inline-block, or consider if they actually need to be paragraph elements, or could they be spans

Comment: A paragraph by definition are self-contained units. Consider using a different tag such as span: `<span id="likes">Likes</span>`

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block;` or create some flexbox layout. But... Can you  please edit the question and put the relevant code here?

Comment: You should put your code into the question and exclude any code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem. I did that for you this time as an example but your question still doesn't make a lot of sense. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I don't see a script that requires two tags

Comment: Please stop suggesting `<span>` just for the looks. We're in 2020, it's about time we stop mixing semantics and layout.

Comment: I've seen your edit. Your HTML is pretty broken (you can't have `<td>`s outside tables), I suggest you fix it to make styling easier. Also, you haven't really shared any attempt to accomplish it!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález If you read the existing code, the existing `<p>` is not semantic, a `<span>` probably makes more sense. Yes, let's use semantic HTML but let's be careful when complaining.

Answer (score 2):

You can put them in `span`s:

```html
<p>
     <span id="Likes">1 Likes</span>
     <span id="DisLikes">1 DisLikes</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to review your HTML elements; you should never use `<td>` the way you are using them. `<td>` are used in `<table>` elements. Your code should look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="section">
    <p class="inline" id="Likes">1 Likes</p>
    <p class="inline" id="DisLikes">1 DisLikes</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<span>` instead of `<p>` . 
By default `<p>` is a paragraph and take the full width of your screen 
[More intels about HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/HTML_text_fundamentals)

Comment: This is not a great solution because a `<p>` tag has a semantic meaning. It is important to understand the fundamentals of "why" this would work and the reason is because a "<p>" tag is a block level element where as a "<span>" is not.

The correct solution is to use css to display the "<p>" tags to "display: inline-block;".

Comment: @sburke In this case, they're not paragraphs anyway, a span would be more semantic. Sure you can use CSS instead of changing the tag but your comment is just wrong in this case

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes you're correct, I missed that detail that it is in a table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A paragraph is a block unit by default. If you want two HTML elements to show on the same line, consider using `span` elements instead of `p`.

```
<span id="Likes">1 Likes</span>
<span id="DisLikes">1 DisLikes</span>
```

Or, if you really, really need the elements to stay as paragraphs, set their CSS `display` to `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this line of code into your CSS file to define the line on each paragraph you do on your HTML file.

```
line-height:26px;
display: inline-block;
```

I am sure this will work on your CSS class, good luck on your project.

Comment: For some reason the code was not posted at start, it has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property `display:inline-flex` and make sure to use this CSS property inside td tag.